# Открытие модального окна в зависимости от кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите как мне реализовать код на JavaScript чтобы модалка открывалась в зависимоит от кнопки. Если клик на кнопку доставка, то модалка с доставкой срабатывает и тд.

```css
.modal {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Доставка</a>
<a href="#" class="btn">Оплата</a>
<a href="#" class="btn">Гарантия</a>

<div class="modal">Доставка</div>
<div class="modal">Оплата</div>
<div class="modal">Гарантия</div>
```

Comment: 1 - Задаем уникальные классы модалкам.
2 - Вешаем onClick: <a onClick="openPayModal" ...>
3 - В функции openPayModal ищем модалку по классу и меняем для нее стиль display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

модалкам добавьте идентификаторы, а кнопкам через data-атрибуты укажите целевую модалку.

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
  let target = $(this).data('target');
  
  alert($(target).text());
});
```

```css
.modal {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-target="#delivery">Доставка</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-target="#payment">Оплата</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-target="#warranty">Гарантия</a>

<div class="modal" id="delivery">Доставка</div>
<div class="modal" id="payment">Оплата</div>
<div class="modal" id="warranty">Гарантия</div>
```